# Map replaced all the same key value of list object

Tags: java

I was trying to replace map details of only selected index from list of bean but it replaced all the value for each list objects which contains the same key. If I am creating new object of map before going to put new value then it's working fine, but I wanted to know the reason why following code misbehave.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    List<PolicyAddlnInsuredBean> lst = new ArrayList<PolicyAddlnInsuredBean>();
    PolicyAddlnInsuredBean pb = new PolicyAddlnInsuredBean();
    Map<String, Map<String, Object>> epInfoMap = new HashMap<String, Map<String,Object>>();

    Map<String,Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    map.put("addtlnInsReqd", "YES");
    map.put("selectedFlg", "No");
    epInfoMap.put("AL", map);
    pb.setEpInfoMap(epInfoMap);
    lst.add(pb);

    epInfoMap = new HashMap<String, Map<String,Object>>();
    map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    map.put("addtlnInsReqd", "YES");
    map.put("selectedFlg", "No");
    epInfoMap.put("AL", map);
    pb.setEpInfoMap(epInfoMap);
    lst.add(pb);

    lst.get(0).getEpInfoMap().get("AL").put("selectedFlg", "Yes");
    System.out.println(lst);
}
```

My Pojo class :

```
public class PolicyAddlnInsuredBean{

  private Map<String,Map<String,Object>> epInfoMap =new HashMap<String, Map<String,Object>>(); 

  public Map<String, Map<String, Object>> getEpInfoMap() {
    return epInfoMap;
  }
  public void setEpInfoMap(Map<String, Map<String, Object>> epInfoMap) {
    this.epInfoMap = epInfoMap;
  }
  @Override
  public String toString() {
      return "PolicyAddlnInsuredBean [epInfoMap=" + epInfoMap + "]";
  }

}
```

Comment: How does it misbehave? What is the expected result and what actually was printed out?

Answer (score 5):

There is only one `pb` object, added twice to `lst` (principle: "check the `new`s").

Comment: Thank You, Now I am clear. It was referring the same object so update all the values.

Answer (score 0):

The same pb object is added twice to the list.So even when you are changing the pb object at 0th index, the change will be reflected at object at 1st index as well.